# ExecutorService fixed pool threads are hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am using following code snippet in our code.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
while(loop 50 times){
    //In the extreme case I will have 50 threads and only 4 will be active and remaining are in queue 
    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
    executor.execute(myThread);//Each Thread process 100,000 records and put in a file
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. It is hanging at second while loop. What might be the reason?
2. Is there any way to terminate Entire thread pool after certain interval?
3. Can I terminate a thread after certain time interval?

Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: Based On some data I will decide iteration count and create thread inside it. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Provide more realistic code. From this base, we cannot be sure if the problem is in the loop or in the task done in your `Runnable` (assuming that `MyThread` is a `Runnable` and has a very bad naming).

Comment: executor.shutdown() will allow the already scheduled task to execute and it will not allow any new task though you have initiated 50 threads. Do you have a sleep in the second while loop? otherwise this will take most of the CPU and the actual will may cause the tasks which are in execution to take more time to complete.

Comment: You can use awaitTermination() to wait till the execution is completed rather than checking the termination status in while loop. awaitTermintation is blocking call and it will come out immediately when the execution is completed.

Comment: @JavaP just curious to know if the below answer resolved your queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.It is hanging at second while loop. What might be the reason?**

The reason for hanging could be because of very few threads compared to the amount of records that needs to be processed and stored in file. If each thread is supposed to process 100,000 records and put in file then 50 thread tasks shared by 4 threads will have to process 5,000,000 records with 50 files. So better to increase the number of threads and check. Also note down time taken by each thread to effectively measure if you are reducing the time taken overall by increasing the number of fixed pool threads.

**2.Is there any way to terminate Entire thread pool after certain interval?**

Yes below code shows that:-

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // blocks/waits for certain interval as specified
executor.shutdownNow(); // Forcefully terminate entire thread pool after the above time.
```

**3.Can I terminate a thread after certain time interval?**

Yes if effectively the reason for terminating a thread is to stop what task it is doing. To achieve this we need to get a reference to the future and wait conditionally for period of time before we forcefully cancel the task and interrupt the thread carrying out the task.

```
        Map<String, Future> tasks = new HashMap<String, Future>();
        while(i++ < 50){
            //In the extreme case I will have 50 threads and only 4 will be active and remaining are in queue 
            Thread myThread = new Thread();
            tasks.put("Thread"+i ,executor.submit(myThread));//Each Thread process 100,000 records and put in a file
        }
        // say you want to terminate Thread2 after 60 seconds
        Future thread2Task = tasks.get("Thread2");
        thread2Task.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        thread2Task.cancel(true); // boolean whether you want to interrupt the thred forcefully
```

Comment: Thats again a probability. It might be taking long time for all the thread tasks to be completed which are submitted to your executor. It would be good to calculate how much time would a task take to get completed which can give us an indication of how long would your last while loop take to stop. You can actually sleep for a few milliseconds in your last while loop so that it doesnot run continuously and gives a breather for threads in the executor to  take turn to run their tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your interest..If I use timeout for both thread and threadpool, only one is working as expected. It is waiting till all threads completion for thread time out and by the time it reaches threadpool it is done with all threads..so there is no use of specifying timeout for threadpool..do you have any solution?

Comment: @JavaP As discussed I feel by calling get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS) on Future you will be waiting for 2 seconds for first thread and after looping te seconds future you would be waiting for 2 more seconds and so on which would lead to inconsistent wait times for different thread task futures. So the ideal way is to wait on the executor task for given period of time which is giving all thread future tasks equal chance and the calling shutdownNow() as described in the above answer point 2.

Comment: Now if time taken for 1 thread is around 2 seconds and since there are 4 threads running concurrently with a maximum of 50 iterations(thread tasks) then you can calculate the await termination as (no of iterations / 4 ) * 2 . This should be your approximate awaitTermination time (you can add a second or two for this to consider the fact that threads may take a little longer time to run in concurrent environment). Do let us know if you could implement successfully in production.

Answer (score 1):

ExecutorServise will have a pool of Threads to execute your Runnable tasks, you defined the size of the pool to be 4, I would change that to be the number of cpus in the machine:

```
int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```

Also, it appears that you are sending Threads to the executor to execute them in one of the available threads in it's pool, It's redundant, you might change your MyThread to a Runnable task.